# Program to search a word in file and print the line that it occurs

Tags: c, file

Write a C program that read a the name of a file and one word from the keyboard. The program must print all lines of the file who has this word.

I can't find a way to make this work.

I did this:

```
char nome_arq[20];

printf("Tell me the name of file: ");
scanf(" %s", nome_arq);

FILE *fp = fopen(nome_arq, "r");

if(!fp) return 0;

char palavra[40];

printf("Tell me the word: ");
scanf(" %s", palavra);

while(!feof(fp)) {
    char palavra2[40];

    fscanf(fp, " %[^' ']", palavra2);

    if(!strcmp(palavra, palavra2)) {
        char linha[400];
        fgets(linha, 400, fp);
        printf("%s\n", linha);
    }
}

return 0;
```

but it just print the line since the word to the end.

Help please.

Comment: If I were doing this, I'd read a line with `fgets` and search for the string with `strstr`. And I'd use `while (fgets(..))` for the loop--`while (!feof(fp))` is pretty much a guaranteed bug.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Thank you bro. I did it. Didn't knew `strstr` function. It's done. Thanks again.